# Relation between Ax=0 and Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm not sure how to solve this. My teacher told me that if $A\vec{x}=0$ has one unique solution (the trivial) then $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ has only one unique solution. But I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: Hint: $A(r-s) = Ar-As$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I'm not sure what you mean by r and s vector.

Comment: If $A\vec x=\vec b$ and $A\vec y=\vec b$, then $A(\vec x-\vec y)=0,$ so...

Comment: Note that you can conclude that $Ax=b$ has *at most* one solution; you can't conclude it has *exactly* one solution.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin. So $A\vec{x}=b$ can also have no solution? How? Do you have an example with real numbers?

Comment: $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&2\\2&3\end{array}\right)$, $b=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Should I then prove that $A\vec{x}=b$ can at the most have one solution if A is (m x n) or (n x n). But if A is (m x n) it can also have no solutions and come with an example? Is that enough?

Comment: The answer is that it has at most $1$, so either $1$ or $0$. You can give examples in which it has $1$, and examples in which it has $0$. It will be the case that if $A$ is $n\times n$ then  it will definitely have *exactly* $1$, but that may be beyond the tools you have on hand to establish.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. I'm sorry. It takes some time before I understand proofs. I guess what you write proves that $A\vec{x}=b$ has at most one solution. But by writing $A(\vec x-\vec y)=0,$ do I then prove that x=y?

Comment: Yes, @Mathomat55; see my answer below

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 6):

I will use boldface for vectors.

We have the following:

> **Theorem.** Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, and $\mathbf{b}$ an $m\times 1$ vector. If $\mathbf{y}_0$ is a solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, then every solution of $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ is of the form $\mathbf{y}_0+\mathbf{s}$, where $\mathbf{s}$ is a solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, and every such vector is a solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$. In other words, the complete list of solutions to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ is given by finding a *particular* solution $\mathbf{y}_0$ to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, and adding the solutions to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$.

(This is one reason homogeneous systems play such an important role in the theory of systems of linear equations).

*Proof.* First, if $\mathbf{y}_0$ is a solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{s}$ is a solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, then
$$A(\mathbf{y}_0+\mathbf{s}) = A\mathbf{y}_0 + A\mathbf{s} = \mathbf{b}+\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{b}.$$
So all such vectors are also solutions. Conversely, if $\mathbf{y}_1$ is also a solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, then $\mathbf{s}=\mathbf{y}_1-\mathbf{y}_0$ is a solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, since
$$A\mathbf{s} = A(\mathbf{y}_1-\mathbf{y}_0) = A\mathbf{y}_1 - A\mathbf{y}_0 = \mathbf{b}-\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}.$$
And $\mathbf{y}_1 = \mathbf{y}_0+\mathbf{s}$, so $\mathbf{y}_1$ is of the desired form. $\Box$

This tells you that *if* there is at least one solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, *then* there are exactly as many solutions to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ as there are to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. It does not tell you that there definitely is a solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, though. It could be that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ is inconsistent, so that it has *no* solutions.

When you know that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ has exactly one solution, you actually can say more, though you may not have the tools to justify it right now. It turns out that in this situation, the matrix $A$ must have $m\geq n$ (if $m\leq n$, more columns than rows, then $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ will always have more than one solution). And if $m=n$, then one can prove that the system $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ *always* has at least (and hence exactly) one solution.

And in fact you would know that the solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ has to be $\mathbf{s}=\mathbf{0}$. If you did not realize this, note that if $\mathbf{s}$ is a solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, then using the theorem with $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}$ tells you that $\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{s}=2\mathbf{s}$ is *also* a solution. So the uniqueness would tell you that $\mathbf{s}=2\mathbf{s}$, and that can only hold if $\mathbf{s}=\mathbf{0}$ (assuming you are working over a field of characteristic $\neq2$... and if you don't know what that means, you are).

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

*Case of a square matrix $A$*

By the rank nullity theorem $A$ injective if and only if it’s kernel is reduced to the zero vector if and only if $A$ is surjective.

*Case where $Ax=b$ has no solution*

Take
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\end{pmatrix} \text{ and }b=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: We have not studied this theorem before in class, so I'm not sure how to use it unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

A useful result on linear systems is the following:

> Let $K$ be a field,  $A$ the matrix of a linear map from $K^n$ to $K^p$, $\:b\in K^p$.
> The linear equation $Ax=b$ ($x\in K^n$) has a solution if & only if the matrix $A$ and the augmented matrix $[A|b]$ have the same rank.
>  Furthermore, this common rank is the codimension of the affine subspace of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

> My teacher told me that if $A\vec x =\vec0$ has one unique solution (the trivial) then $A\vec x =\vec b$  has only one unique solution. But I don't know how to prove this.

Simply, as hinted in comments by [Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin),

if $A\vec x=\vec b$ and $A\vec y=\vec b$, then $A\vec x - A\vec y=0$, so by linearity of $A$ then $A(\vec x-\vec y)=\vec0$,

so $\vec x-\vec y=\vec 0$, so $\vec x=\vec y$, so if there is a solution to $A\vec x=\vec b$, then it is unique.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now! :)